# copiar archivos de una carpeta a otra

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente programa:

```
public static void main(String args[]) { 

                File origen = new File("C:\\Users\\Montse\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Copiar2\\hola.txt");
                File destino = new File("C:\\Users\\Montse\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Copiar2\\backupVisibles\\hola.txt");

                try {
                        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(origen);
                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destino);

                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;

                        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                                out.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }

                        in.close();
                        out.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe){
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                }


        }
```

No consigo ver como conseguir lo siguiente:

Necesito Poner por argumento args[0]  el parametro del directorio actual.

es decir: 
String sDirectorio = "C:\Users\Montse\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Copiar2";
File f = new File(sDirectorio);

y que copie el archivo que yo ponga en el parametro args[1] por ejemplo el archivo hola.txt

Lo máximo que he conseguido es este programa que básicamente lo que hace es copiarme un archivo de una carpeta a otra, pero no consigo lo que de verdad necesito.. :(

gracias!

PD: Añado texto por que creo que no me he explicado del todo bien.

Es decir con el primer ARGS[0] necesito que ponga el directorio actual.
En el segundo ARGS[1] necesito que X archivo por ejemplo el archivo hola.txt ( es decir yo lo pondré en los parametros el que yo escoja.. )

Y ese archivo se guardará en la carpeta que yo quiera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjunto una posible solucion a tú duda :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Error el número de parametros debe de ser tres <Directorio Origen> <Fichero>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        String pathOrigen = args[0];
        String pathDestino = pathOrigen + "backup\\"; 
        // Define aqui tu directorio destino
        String fichero = args[1];
        File ficheroCopiar = new File(pathOrigen, fichero);
        File ficheroDestino = new File(pathDestino, fichero);
        if (ficheroCopiar.exists()) {
            Files.copy(Paths.get(ficheroCopiar.getAbsolutePath()), Paths.get(ficheroDestino.getAbsolutePath()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } else {
            System.out.println("El fichero " + fichero + " no existe en el directorio " + pathOrigen);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Aqui](http://blog.softmolina.com.mx/wp/2016/12/13/cambiar-de-nombre-mover-eliminar-o-copiar-un-archivo-en-java/) encontraras como mover y copiar un archivo

La clase `java.nio.file.Files`, implementa una serie de métodos estáticos para las operaciones de manejo de ficheros(archivos), entre los cuales está el método `move()`.

Utilizando este método, podemos escribir una función que mueve un archivo de un directorio a otro. El método `move()` recibe un argumento `CopyOptions`, con el que podemos especificar que sobrescribe el fichero de destino si ya existía.

```
package mx.com.softmolina;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

/**
 *
 * @author SoftMolina
 */
public class MoverArchivoMove {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path origenPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\carpeta1\\ejemplo1.txt");
        Path destinoPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\carpeta2\\ejemplo1.txt");

        try {
            Files.move(origenPath, destinoPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

**Copiar un archivo en Java**

La clase `java.nio.file.Files`, implementa una serie de métodos estáticos para las operaciones de manejo de ficheros(archivos), entre los cuales está el método `copy()`.

Utilizando este método, podemos escribir una función que copia un archivo en otro lado. El método `copy()` recibe un argumento `CopyOptions`, con el que podemos especificar que sobrescribe el fichero de destino si ya existía.

```
    package mx.com.softmolina;

    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    /**
     *
     * @author SoftMolina
     */
    public class CopiarArchivo {

        static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

        public CopiarArchivo(String origenArchivo, String destinoArchivo) {
            try {
                Path origenPath = Paths.get(origenArchivo);
                Path destinoPath = Paths.get(destinoArchivo);
                //sobreescribir el fichero de destino si existe y lo copia
                Files.copy(origenPath, destinoPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

       public static void main(String args[]) {
        if(args.length == 2)
            new copiarArchivo(args[0], args[1]);
        else
            System.out.println("Debe ingresar dos parametros");
       }

    }
```

O encontré este ejemplo: [Aqui](https://axiacore.com/blog/2008/06/copiar-un-archivo-a-otro-en-java/)

```
import java.io.*;

    public class FileCopy {
        public FileCopy(String sourceFile, String destinationFile) {
            System.out.println("Desde: " + sourceFile);
            System.out.println("Hacia: " + destinationFile);

            try {
                File inFile = new File(sourceFile);
                File outFile = new File(destinationFile);

                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inFile);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

                int c;
                while( (c = in.read() ) != -1)
                    out.write(c);

                in.close();
                out.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Hubo un error de entrada/salida!!!");
            }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            if(args.length == 2)
                new FileCopy(args[0], args[1]);
            else
                System.out.println("Debe ingresar dos parametros");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Solo puedo copiar no mover. El problema que tengo es que mi programa ya me hace esa función y funciona perfectamente. Pero me falta que en vez de ponerlo manualmente lo ponga en ARGS. El primer arg para el directorio actual y el segundo arg para un archivo File.

Comment: Modifique la respuesta esperando sea lo que necesitas

Answer (score 1):

Si creas un `jar` ejecutable de tu programa puedes llamarlo desde la consola simplemente como:

```
java -jar MiApp.jar ruta/a/fuente ruta/a/destino
```

Eso te va llamar tu método `main` con los argumentos:

```
arg[0]="ruta/a/fuente";
arg[1]="ruta/a/destino";
```

y puedes cambíar tu código para trabajar con eso en vez de los constantes.

Comment: el problema es que el arg2 es un archivo no otra ruta.. es decir la idea es que me coje la ruta que estoy. Me coge de esa ruta el archivo que yo quiero arg[2] y lo copia en otra carpeta la que yo escoja.

Comment: Tu tienes todo el control lo que haces con los argumentos pasados. Pudes comprobar si es una ruta que existe, podrías inerpretarlo como nombre de archivo - eso es la magia de turing complete - declara que quieres hacer, y lo hacemos.

Answer (score 1):

File tiene un [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) justo para tu caso. Un parámetro para el directorio y otro para el archivo.

Substituye :

```
File origen = new File("C:\\Users\\Montse\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Copiar2\\hola.txt");
```

por:

```
File origen = new File(args[0], args[1]);
```

Y deja el resto igual. Ahora `origen` se refiere al archivo indicado en `args[1]` que esté en el directorio indicado en `args[0]`.

Tal que así el archivo de destino sería fijo. El que has puesto en el programa. Si quieres que sea uno elegido  por parámetros al llamar el programa puedes usar la misma técnica.

Answer (score 0):

args sería definido como un String array:

```
String args[] = {"C:\\Users\\Montse\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Copiar2\\hola.txt","Bohra","C:\\Users\\Montse\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Copiar2\\backupVisibles\\hola.txt"};
```

llamarías `main()` de esta forma:

```
  MyClass.main(args[]);
```

y dentro de `main()` obtendrías los valores de esta forma:

```
  File origen = new File(args[0]);
  File destino = new File(args[1]);
```

Comment: Creo que no me he explicado del todo bien..

Es decir con el primer ARGS[0] necesito que ponga el directorio hasta ahí con tu info perfecto. 

pero en el segundo ARGS[1] necesito que X archivo por ejemplo el archivo hola de dentro del directorio del ARGS[0] se copie en otra carpeta.

Es decir yo tengo que poner el directorio y un archivo y eso se me copia en la carpeta que yo elija.

Comment: Te refieres a que main() reciba como argumentos un valor String con una ruta y un valor File ?

Comment: si.. el valor String es la ruta actual del directorio. Y el File cualquier fichero que yo ponga por ejemplo Hola.txt

Answer (score 0):

Haber mi amigo ahí le va mi propuesta.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    if(args.length == 2){

      File origen = new File(args[0] + "\\" + args[1]);

      //Ruta que tu elijas [no dinámico]
      File destino = new File("C:\\Users\\Montse\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Copiar2\\backupVisibles\\hola.txt");

      try {
              InputStream in = new FileInputStream(origen);
              OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destino);

              byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
              int len;

              while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                      out.write(buf, 0, len);
              }

              in.close();
              out.close();
      } catch (IOException ioe){
              ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

}
```

> Uso

```
//Ruta raiz 
String pathDirectorio = "C:\\Users\\Montse\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Copiar2";
//Nombre del archivo
String file = "texto.txt"


String[] args = {pathDirectorio, file};
//Llama a su clase método main
MiClase.main(args);
```

Espero que le sirva mi estimado adiós.